# Why does return True have to be outside the if statement and the for loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to see if lst2 is the reverse of lst1.

For the following code, why does `return True` have to be outside the if statement. When I put else: return False with the if statement, both of the prints return True (which is incorrect). Thank you!

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
  for index1 in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[index1] != lst2[(-1 - index1)]:
      return False
  return True


print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]))
print(reversed_list([1, 5, 3], [3, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: Read [ask] - Maybe In the `for` loop, why don’t you try printing the values you’re comparing? Are they different?

Comment: You could run your code in this platform and see it's running every step visually - http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put it into the `if`, i.e. into the same conditionality as the `return False`, but after it, then it will never be executed, because the function will always have been left with the first `return`. Or it will always be executed inside the `if`, before, leaving it and thereby unintendedly overriding the intended `False`. This seems is what you are observing.

If you put it into the loop (but outside the `if`) it will be executed during the first iteration of the loop, i.e. much too early.

If you put it into the loop, but with an `else`, it will still be executed too early. at the first case of not `False`. This is still not what you want, because you only want a `True` when there is no `False` anywhere in the loop, not already at the first case of not `False`.

You only want to return a true boolean if the loop gets completly through without ever triggering the False. You want that because otherwise you might miss cases of False.

This is why the position you describe and use in the shown code, outside of both, the `if` and the loop, is the only correct way.

Comment: Thank you for explaining all 3 places to put the `return True` . However, in one attempt, I used `else: return False` . Why did it also return True for lists that don't match? It returned True for both of the following: 
`print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]))
print(reversed_list([1, 5, 3], [3, 2, 1]))`

Comment: Good point, I added an explanation for that.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is a lighter method to a brute force approach.

With brute force, the second list is reversed and then all the elements of both lists are compared. That's a lot of wasted resources, especially if the lists are massive in length.

The approach provided in your Q utilizes a pointer, which essentially allows you to "stop early." Instead of sorting the second list, iterate over the elements and compare them. If they match, move on to the next elements. If they do not match, escape early and `return False`. With this approach, you cannot return `True` until all the elements in the lists are compared. (Hence, `return True` is outside the for loop.)

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement immediately stops the execution of a function or method.

In this way, your function stops at the first difference and returns  `False`. If all tested elements are equal, then the loop finishes without that `return False` statement and continues with the next statement which is  `return True` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why does else: return True make both pairs of list return True? If there is one element that tests negative, shouldn't it return as False?

Comment: If you had if lst1[index1] != lst2[(-1 - index1)]:
      return False
  else: return True  then you would only test the first element, since there would be a return statement in every branch of the if, which would sop every further execution

Comment: Oh I see, since there is already a solution for the if (the else statement), it would stop the loop and execute the else after testing the first element. Thank you! That makes so much sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you need, but this is a way of checking if l1 is the same as l2 reversed.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [3, 2, 1]
l2.reverse()

if l1 == l2:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: ↑ Brute force. Index matching is better.

Comment: I like this way as well! does .reverse actually change l2 into [1, 2, 3]? If it does, I'd probably have to make a new variable before reversing.

Comment: @KhoiNguyen yes, it reverses l2 in-place.